# Search and replace in 1 step instead of 3 with Vim regex

Tags: node.js, regex, vim, replace

I have this code that I'd like to transform:

```
       const createFacebookAdVideoPayload   = {
         const accountId = faker.datatype.uuid();
         const publicLink = faker.internet.url();
         const videoName = faker.lorem.word();

         const facebookToken = undefined;
         const params = null;
         const businessId = faker.datatype.uuid();
       }
```

I have the habit to use those vim commands for this usually:

- `'<,'>s/const//g`
- `'<,'>s/ =/:/g`
- `'<,'>s/;/,/g`

The end result now being:

```
        const createFacebookAdVideoPayload = {
          accountId: faker.datatype.uuid(),
          publicLink: faker.internet.url(),
          videoName: faker.lorem.word(),
          facebookToken: undefined,
          params: null,
          businessId: faker.datatype.uuid(),
        };
```

Isn't there any smart regex possible to do it in one go?

Comment: What environment are you working in? Maybe a scripting commande would be note appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

When performing a complex substitution that involves several parts of a line, the usual approach is to use so-called "capture groups". In Vim, it looks like this…

- Original line:

  ```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  ```
- Pattern:

  ```
  \(Lorem\).*\(dolor\).*\(amet\.\)
  ```

  We capture what we want to keep and discard the rest.

  - `\(Lorem\)` matches `Lorem` as group 1,
  - `.*` matches any number of any character,
  - `\(dolor\)` matches `dolor` as group 2,
  - `.*` matches any number of any character,
  - `\(amet.\)` matches `amet.` as group 3.

  We could also capture what we don't want if that makes things easier or neater.
- Replacement:

  ```
  \1 foo \2 bar \3
  ```

  - `\1` reuses capture group 1,
  - `<space>foo<space>`,
  - `\2` reuses capture group 2,
  - `<space>bar<space>`,
  - `\3` reuses capture group 3.
- Desired line:

  ```
  Lorem foo dolor bar amet.
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Capture the parts between `const`,  `=` and `;` using `\(.*\)` and put them back using back-references `\n` (where `n` is the group number).

```
:%s/const\(.*\) =\(.*\);/\1:\2,/
```

You don't need the *global* flag `/g` because there's at most 1 match per line.

I'm not *that* familiar with vim, but I don't think you need `'<,'` either, because the above command worked for me without it.

Comment: 1. The range is presumably there because OP made a visual selection first. 2. You should remove the `const` from the replacement part. 3. Speaking of not needed, the final `/` is not needed either.

Comment: @romainl `const` is there to avoid unintended altering of lines that have `=` and `;` but not `const`

Comment: OP doesn't want that `const`, though.

Comment: @romainl oh yeah! Thanks. Didn't notice that